# How to pass data via segue or delegate from a TableViewCell to a CollectionViewController in swift 4 or later?

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, segue, uisplitviewcontroller

I am having a problem in an assignment that I am currently doing. I am trying to set a property as well as edit my CollectionViewController named ImageGalleryViewController when a row in my TableViewController named GalleryChooserViewController is chosen. I have been successful in passing data but I can't drag or drop images in the ImageGalleryViewController after I chose a row in the GalleryChooserViewController.

Here are some of the code snippets from the respective view controller.

**GalleryChooserViewController**

```
weak var delegate : GalleryChooserDelegate?
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    chosenAlbum = albums[indexPath.row]
    delegate?.choose(gallery: chosenAlbum)
    if let detailViewController = delegate as? ImageGalleryViewController,
      let detailNavigationController = detailViewController.navigationController {
        splitViewController?.showDetailViewController(detailNavigationController, sender: nil)
    }

}
```

**ImageGalleryViewController**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, performDropWith coordinator: UICollectionViewDropCoordinator) {
    let destinationIndexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath ?? IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

    for item in coordinator.items {

        if let sourceIndexPath = item.sourceIndexPath {
            if let image = item.dragItem.localObject as? UIImage {
                collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                    gallery.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.item)
                    gallery.insert(image, at: destinationIndexPath.item)
                    collectionView.deleteItems(at: [sourceIndexPath])
                    collectionView.insertItems(at: [destinationIndexPath])
                    storedImages.updateValue(gallery, forKey: chosenGallery)
                })
                coordinator.drop(item.dragItem, toItemAt: destinationIndexPath)
            }
        } else {

            let placeholderContext = coordinator.drop(item.dragItem, to:UICollectionViewDropPlaceholder(insertionIndexPath: destinationIndexPath, reuseIdentifier: "DropPlaceholderCell"))
            item.dragItem.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: NSURL.self){ (provider, error) in

                DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
                    if let url = provider as? URL {
                        let urlToBeFetched = url.imageURL
                        let urlContents = try? Data(contentsOf: urlToBeFetched)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let imageData = urlContents, url.imageURL == urlToBeFetched {
                                self.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                                placeholderContext.commitInsertion(dataSourceUpdates: { insertionIndexPath in
                                    self.gallery.insert(self.image!, at: insertionIndexPath.item)
                                    self.storedImages.updateValue(self.gallery, forKey: self.chosenGallery)

                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        placeholderContext.deletePlaceholder()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
extension ImageGalleryViewController : GalleryChooserDelegate {
func choose(gallery: String) {
    chosenGallery = gallery
    if let gallery = storedImages[gallery] {
        self.gallery = gallery
     }
    else {
        storedImages.updateValue(self.gallery, forKey: gallery)
       }
}
```

}

**SceneDelegate.swift**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard
        let splitViewController = window?.rootViewController as? UISplitViewController,
        let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
        let masterViewController = leftNavController.viewControllers.first as? GalleryChooserViewController,
        let detailViewController = (splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController)?.topViewController as? ImageGalleryViewController
        else { fatalError() }

      let firstAlbum = masterViewController.albums.first
      detailViewController.chosenGallery = firstAlbum!
      masterViewController.delegate = detailViewController
      detailViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
      detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
    }
```